# How to create golden filter using KineticJS?

Tags: kineticjs

I need to give golden filter to images in canvas. does anyone know how to do it? I know how to apply filter but i am not able to produce golden filter effect.

Comment: what you have done ??? please show your effort.

Comment: i was using
image.setFilter(Kinetic.Filters.Colorize);
image.setFilterColorizeColor([255,223,0]); 
to give it golden touch but i think it wont work as i am using only one color

Comment: Could you better describe the effect you desire?

Comment: Actually i am trying to apply Golden filter to image in canvas.

I tried filter using following code:
image.setFilter(Kinetic.Filters.Colorize);
image.setFilterColorizeColor([255,223,0]);

to make it golden but i am not getting the exact golden filter.. Does anyone know how to give proper golden filter to image?